# Remove cell formatting when copying cells from one range to another

Tags: excel, vba

My code for copying a row from one worksheet into another.

```
For Each i In Worksheets("BOM").Range(rangeStr)
    Set cell = dataCol.Find(What:=i.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "part not found"
    Else
        dataRow = "B" & cell.Row & ":I" & cell.Row
        bomRow = "B" & i.Row & ":I" & i.Row
        Worksheets("datasheet").Range(dataRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("BOM").Range(bomRow)
    End If

Next
```

The cells are formatted differently, some have red backgrounds, green etc. How do I copy only the values within the cell and none of the formatting?

Comment: Use `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel)

Answer (score 2):

You can alter your single `.Copy/Destination` line to this, to achieve a Copy/Paste Special - Values..

```
Worksheets("datasheet").Range(dataRow).Copy
Worksheets("BOM").Range(bomRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Note: you need the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to deselect the Copy range.

---

**HOWEVER**, you don't need to `Copy` at all. Just set the values of the cells to those of the other like so:

```
Worksheets("BOM").Range(bomRow).Value = Worksheets("datasheet").Range(dataRow)
```